# Within a list of vectors, convert each vector to a string then convert to dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

I have a list of vectors, j, that looks like this:

```
>j
[[1]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "c" "c" 

[[3]]
[1] "d" "d" "d" "a" "a" 
.
. 
.
```

I would like to transform this into a dataframe that has one column with each vectors contents concatenated together. So the column would look like:

```
  Column_Name
1       a b c 
2         c c 
3   d d d a a
```

I have tried using Replace() function as well as a loop where I would use  after:

```
for (x in 1:length(j)){ 
  j[x] = paste(j[x], collapse = " ")
}

 j <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(j), nrow=length(j), byrow=T)
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As you have tried yourself, the `sapply` function together with the `collapse` argument of `paste` should do it all wrapped into a `data.frame`:

```
# Toy data
set.seed(1)
j <- replicate(5, rep(sample(letters, 1), sample(1:10,1)))
print(j)
#[[1]]
#[1] "g" "g" "g" "g"
#
#[[2]]
# [1] "o" "o" "o" "o" "o" "o" "o" "o" "o" "o"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "f" "f" "f" "f" "f" "f" "f" "f" "f"
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "y" "y" "y" "y" "y" "y" "y"
#
#[[5]]
#[1] "q"

# Collapse each element and wrap into a data.frame
res <- data.frame("Column_name" = sapply(j, paste, collapse = " "))
print(res)
#          Column_name
#1             g g g g
#2 o o o o o o o o o o
#3   f f f f f f f f f
#4       y y y y y y y
#5                   q
```

The `sapply` applies the `paste`-function on each element of the `list` to create a character vector of the concatenated list elements. The `data.frame` constructor simply converts that output to the wanted output.

Comment: `data.frame(Column_name = sapply(ll,paste,collapse=" "))`. No need of the quotes in  `"Column_name"`

Comment: @Onyambu Indeed, the quotes can be omitted. But this also works. Is this considered "bad style" or otherwise "dangerous"? I think it makes it clear that the program does not look for some `Column_name` object (which it doesn't if it exists or not).

Comment: You can think of it as an assignment. You assign to column_name not to "column_name", eg we do `>a=3` not `>"a"=3`

Answer (score 0):

Once provide the `name` to list and then use `stack` to convert list in a data.frame. Finally, `dplyr` package is used to collapse vector from common element separated by .

Sample Data is taken from `@AndersEllernBilgrau`'s answer.

```
set.seed(1)
j <- replicate(5, rep(sample(letters, 1), sample(1:10,1)))

names(j) <- seq_along(j)

library(dplyr)
stack(j) %>% group_by(ind) %>%
  summarise(Column_Name = paste0(values, collapse = " ")) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-ind)

# # A tibble: 5 x 1
# Column_Name        
# <chr>              
# 1 g g g g            
# 2 o o o o o o o o o o
# 3 f f f f f f f f f  
# 4 y y y y y y y      
# 5 q 
#
```

Comment: `aggregate(.~ind,stack(setNames(j,1:length(j))),paste,collapse=" ")`

Comment: @Onyambu Yea. Very correct. Thank can be another option.